# Error icon and popup message in setError

Tags: android

I have 4 `EditText`s in my signup activity. When a user fills the form and moves to the next field, I validate the previous field. If it is correct, I put a **tick icon**. If it's incorrect, I put the standard error icon.

I've overridden the `setError` method to achieve it. This is because `setError` comes with a pop-up message by default, and I don't want any messages when the field is correctly filled. I only want the **tick icon**.

My problem is, I do need to show the error-popup message when a field is incorrectly filled. But since I've overridden it, it's not shown.

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {
        setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null);
    }
}
```

So, my question is: How could I use the original behaviour of `setError` when the icon I pass doesn't match with my tick icon.

PS: I tried using `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` for correct validation and `setError` for incorrect validation. But, that gave me inconsistent errors. That's why I decided to use `setError` only to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Write your custom setCustomError method with message and call edit text's `setError` overriden method in it.